# need clarification on process virtualisation with containers created by "systemd-nspawn"

Tags: linux, virtualization, systemd, container

I have created a container with "systemd-nspawn" command.
Inside that container, with "route" command I could get ip address of default gateway and could ping it.
Now, "ps -ecf" in the host system (outside container) shows "ping" process.

man page of "systemd-nspawn" says it virtualises process tree, the various IPC subsystems and the host and domain name.

my dought is, if "systemd-nspawn" virtualises process tree, why am i seeing "ping " process in "ps -ecf" outside the 
container??

I could also observe this in reverse case i.e "ping" from host and "ps -ecf " inside container.

## logs:

1) create container and ping:
   directory chroot in below command has a debian image obtained from "debootsrtap"

root@vig-debian:/home/vignesh/docker_tutorials# systemd-nspawn -D chroot
Spawning container chroot on /home/vignesh/docker_tutorials/chroot.
Press ^] three times within 1s to kill container.
/etc/localtime is not a symlink, not updating container timezone.
root@chroot:~#
root@chroot:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
10.0.2.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 eth0
10.12.4.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
root@chroot:~# ping 10.0.2.2
PING 10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.322 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.440 ms

2) "ps " in host

root@vig-debian:/home/vignesh/docker_tutorials# ps -ecf | grep "ping"
root      3460  3452 TS   19 16:49 pts/1    00:00:00 ping 10.0.2.2
root      3462  2493 TS   19 16:49 pts/2    00:00:00 grep ping
root@vig-debian:/home/vignesh/docker_tutorials#
root@vig-debian:/home/vignesh/docker_tutorials# machinectl
MACHINE                          CONTAINER SERVICE
chroot                           container nspawn

1 machines listed.

Answer (score 0):

The host can see and send signal to all container processes.

Doing the test from two containers you will see that the processes are not visible.